# Base64 string from JWT to json

Tags: java, json, base64, jwt

When I try to parse header from jwt as base64 to string then the output is :

> {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"1234"

without last bracket, but when I decode the same base64 string for example here: https://www.base64decode.org/ then the json has correct format.

function that I use:

```
   public void test() {
            String encodedToken = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjEyMzQifQ";
            System.out.println(new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encodedToken)));
        }
```

What can be wrong?

EDIT: Java 7 is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to encode `{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"1234"}` in [base64](https://www.base64encode.org/)

You will see `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjEyMzQifQ==`

`==` - is a [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding)

I think that problem is `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary` use representation of [xsd:base64Binary](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_base64Binary.html) (RFC 2045). But in RFC 2045 padding is mandatory.

You can use this way (java.util.Base64):

```
public void test() {
    String encodedToken = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjEyMzQifQ";
    System.out.println(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedToken.getBytes())));
}
```

java.util.Base64 uses RFC 4648 (padding is optional).

Comment: You're right, padding was the problem, but I have to use Java 7.

Comment: @user11196410 you can use [apache-commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(String base64String)

Answer (score 0):

and welcome on StackOverflow.
According to [this](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/143#issuecomment-272398551) answer on Github, `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary()` has some bugs and doesn't output the correct decoded string.

If you're using Java 8 or higher you can decode this way:

```
String base64 = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjEyMzQifQ";
byte[] temp = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64.getBytes());

System.out.println(new String(temp));
```

importing class `java.util.Base64`

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have to use java 7, but I've found that there is a problem with padding so I add it manually.